# Export image with clear edges (no gradient pixels)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector

I have a vector file with about 150 vectors in diferent grayscale colors and I need to export image with clear edges.

For example black and white border should'nt have any aditional colours - only black and white.

[image]

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Photoshop or Illustrator? you added both tags. What format are you trying to export to?

Comment: There are many questions on this site regarding anti-alias, have you tried searching first?

Comment: I'm using both softwares, PNG format. I actualy didn't know it's called anti-alias, thanks for tip!

Comment: The effect you wish to achieve has aliased edges that appear to be jagged due to the pixelation (rendering) of the image. This is blurred to appear straight from a greater distance with an "anti-aliasing" software routine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The soft edges are a result of [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing). There is, as far as I'm aware, no way to export a raster image from Illustrator without anti-aliasing (although I may be wrong). You can however turn off anti-aliasing (for certain things) in Photoshop very easily...

Open up your vector file in Photoshop and uncheck "Anti-aliased" in the import dialog (and choose an appropriate pixel size etc while you're at it) and you're done.

Take this vector from Illustrator:

[image]

Opened in Photoshop at 60 × 60 pixels with anti-aliasing off:

[image]

Which gives us this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

Export the vector image as a PNG, but at a significantly higher resolution than you need, and then open it in Photoshop, and rescale the image smaller, making sure you set the interpolation method to "Nearest Neighbour (preserve hard edges)".

Then if necessary, you could potentially rescale the image larger again, using the same interpolation method, to give it that pixel art look.